# Parse JSON to variable or MySQL

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

Sorry for the question I am not PHP skiller :)

I have a problem with parsing data from JSON.
This is my JSON after dump

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($response, true);
$c = count($data['products']);
var_dump($data);

array(4) {
  ["products"]=>
  array(23347) {
    [0]=>
    array(25) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "DOOKY Strieška"
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["count"]=>
      float(0)
      ["measureType"]=>
      string(2) "ks"
      ["price"]=>
      float(20.83)
      ["vat"]=>
      float(20)
      ["stockCardNumber"]=>
      string(6) "000004"
      ["typeId"]=>
      int(1)
      ["warehouseCode"]=>
      string(3) "MOL"
      ["timestamp"]=>
      string(19) "2019-05-09T10:38:30"
      ["foreignName"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customText"]=>
      string(12) "silver stars"
      ["warrantyPeriod"]=>
      float(0)
      ["weightPerUnit"]=>
      float(0)
      ["volumePerUnit"]=>
      float(0)
      ["numberingSequenceCode"]=>
      string(2) "SK"
      ["ean"]=>
      string(13) "5038278982969"
      ["stn"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["jkpov"]=>
      string(6) "126367"
      ["din"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["bn"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["plu"]=>
      int(0)
      ["warrantyPeriodTypeId"]=>
      int(0)
      ["priceWithVat"]=>
      float(25)
      ["eshop"]=>
      NULL
    }
```

I need to get every EAN, JKPOV, COUNT to variable, and insert to MySQL

I have this code but it doesn't work properly, because not write me all data. But in `var_dump($data);` I have this missing data...

```
$i=0;
for ($i=0; $i <= $c; $i++) {
$ean = $data['products'][$i]['ean'];
$count = $data['products'][$i]['count'];
$jkpov = $data['products'][$i]['jkpov'];
conf::$db->query("insert ignore into sklad set `ean`='$ean', `jkpov`='$jkpov', `count`='$count'");
$i++; }
```

Comment: `for ($i=0; $i <= $c; $i++) {  ... $i++; }` You increment twice `$i`

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use prepared statements

Comment: oh .. i am stupid :)) thanx!